# Embeded Youtube video not playing locally, fine when online

Tags: youtube-api

When I embed Youtube video on a page and test it locally nothing happens or the browser even locks up, depending on the browser. Publish the page, test online and it works fine. Obviously not an ideal develop/test scenario. I'm using the iframe embed code from Youtube.

It sure seems like a cross domain security issue but I see no errors using Firebug and haven't found any reference to that nor anyone with a similar problem. Probably just missing something but I'm stumped. I don't like being stumped... for long.

Example that works online but not locally even if this is the only code in the body:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/INg83kArY4g?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

BTW, no problem embedding and playing the same video locally when hosted on my own web server (not locally). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that file will not load locally is because you are using a protocol relative URL when defining the `src` attribute.
When the browser parses the `src` it will prepend the scheme(http: or https:) that the page is viewed in. If the page is being viewed locally, your browser will prepend `file` to the URL and that will result in an invalid URL.

You can remedy the issue by inserting a scheme on the `src` e.g.

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/INg83kArY4g?rel=0"
```

or by serving up that page on a local server.

Reference
[Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)

Comment: Yes! I pretty much understood why there was no http/https. Totally didn't realize it would mean file: was added locally but that makes sense. Thanks for the solution and the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'http:' to the beginning of the src attribute:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/INg83kArY4g?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```